# why does intellij take Vm args as main class name?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, jar

I try to run my project in intellij as follows:

[image]

But I get an error:

[image]

Why is that?

VM args shouldn't include the main class. That's what i specified in the Dialog under `"Main class"`.

I have tried full path and it didn't help.

all I want to do it to simulate the execution of this shell script:

```
java -DqueryString=myValue -cp RTSimulator.jar:junit-4.11.jar HCRunner HeadlessClientE2ET#sendSearchRequest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what "program arguments" are for. VM options are things like `-Xmx512m` or `-Dfoo=bar`: things that come after `java`, but before the main class name in the command:

```
java -cp ... <VM argument> main.class.Name <program arguments>
```